# how to build ROM for raspberri pi from aosp

Tags: build, raspberry-pi, android-source, rom

How to build aosp for raspberri pi without UI. After build how to build ROM for raspberri-pi using cross compilation.

Answer (score 0):

UI is an integral part of Android OS. You will have to make heavy modifications to the architecture of Android, to remove all UI related stacks & frameworks, and make the OS responsive to non-touch inputs.

If on the other hand you are interested in regular AOSP port to Pi, there are a number of such attempts:
https://github.com/tab-pi/platform_manifest
https://github.com/NimaMX/platform_manifest